# Codename One - Show Next Form Only after Animation on SplashScreen is Complete

Tags: java, android, java-me, codenameone

I have a splash screen implementation on Codename One with an animated text sequence. I do not want to use the nextForm property on my Splash Form since I want the sequence complete before I navigate. Hence, I have used showForm. It works fine on the emulator but when I test on a real device, the next form I have loaded programmatically takes time to load, the transition is slow and sometimes it crashes. I cant seem to figure out why...

I have included the sample code below:

```
@Override
protected void beforeSplash(Form f) {
// If the resource file changes the names of components this call will break notifying you that you should fix the code
    super.beforeSplash(f);
    final String text = "Sample text to be animated here for testing purpose!";
    final SpanLabel l = findSloganLabel(f);

    Animation anim = new Animation() {
        private long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        public boolean animate() {
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int i = l.getText().length();
            if (t - lastTime >= 450) {
                if (i == text.length()) {
                    showForm("Register", null);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Animating Label...");
                    if (i == text.length() - 1) {
                        l.setText(text);
                        l.revalidate();
                    } else {
                        l.setText(text.substring(0, i) + "_");
                        l.revalidate();
                    }
                }
                lastTime = t;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
        }
    };

    f.registerAnimated(anim);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two simple options, the first which I think it better is to not use the "next form" property and then just invoke `showForm("mainFormName", null)` when the animation completes.

The second is really how the next form was designed to work, its designed for you to do a background process on a background thread that might take time, to simulate this we sleep for a few seconds but you should override that method to do whatever you want. Just override this in your state machine and do whatever you want:

```
protected boolean processBackground(Form f) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shai Almog. I had used the first option if you look at the codes i included, It works fine. The major issue is that the form transition is pretty slow, when the form loada afterwards, it takes about 30 - 60 seconds before I am able to input data into the textfields. Thats why I felt I was doing something wrong ... ?

Comment: I just took off the animation and simpley left a static splash screen with the nextForm property set. The application is still very slow on Android and even crashes atimes, strangely, Tipster, works fine on the same device. What do you think could be wrong?

Comment: Your animation code is very slow since it invokes revalidate which is generally a bad thing to do in animation and an even worse thing to do on every frame. When you invoke the showForm make sure the animation method always returns false or that you removed the animation from the form before hand.
Its also good practice to accept correct Answers.

Comment: Sorry about the accepting correct answers issue. I try but my reputation is just 11 points and I need 15 to accept thats why I havent accepted any yet :( ... What can I use in place of revalidate, I currently use revalidate because the spanLabel doesnt grow with the characters except I use it, is there any other alternative?

Comment: Just found out I had been votng up instead of accepting, I have just been able to accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with with what you did is that animate() is called in every EDT cycle (a lot up to 60 times per second!). Revalidate essentially forces ANOTHER repaint, layout and a deep/complex EDT cycle. Normally this isn't awful but during transition we speed up the EDT to get a smoother animation and it chokes with all the revalidates flooding it. You can throttle the animation down by making it happen every 3rd  or 4th animation cycle. Also if you disable it during the transition as I explained above it shouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void postSplash(Form f) {
        UITimer timer = new UITimer(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showForm("MainForm", null);
            }
        });
        timer.schedule(XX-MiliSec, false, f);
    }
```

So in your splash form's postForm method add timer..
And schedule it after XX Milli-seconds (whatever your animation duration is)

It will execute showForm() method after that mentioned Milli-seconds

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an [AnimationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
              @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

              }

              @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                showForm();
              }

              @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

              }
            });)
```

Comment: That's for Android, not Codename One so its incorrect.